# Infinite loop when applying style dynamically to BasicTextField in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm facing a challenge with Jetpack Compose. My objective is to dynamically apply bold styling to specific portions of the text within a BasicTextField based on the user's input and the current cursor position using a button.

For testing purposes, my code automatically sets everything to bold. Eventually, my goal is not to bold the entire content but only selected parts. However, when I attempt to apply the styling within the onValueChange callback or derived state (I tried both - see examples below), it results in a recursive loop where "on value change" prints infinetely to the log.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    StyledTextFieldWithToggleBoldButton()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

    @Composable
    fun StyledTextFieldWithToggleBoldButton() {
    
        var rawText by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
    
        // Derived state for styled input
        val styledText: TextFieldValue by remember(rawText) {
            derivedStateOf {
                Log.d("testing", "derived state")
                val annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
                    withStyle(SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)) {
                        append(rawText.text)
                    }
                }
                TextFieldValue(annotatedString, rawText.selection, rawText.composition)
            }
        }
    
        Column {
            BasicTextField(
                value = styledText,
                onValueChange = {
                    // Only update the raw input here
                    Log.d("testing", "on value change")
                    rawText = it
                },
                textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.Black),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.White)
                    .padding(16.dp),
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
            Button(onClick = {}) {
                Text("Toggle Bold")
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is simpler example to use that also causes this infinite loop:

```
@Composable
fun StyledTextFieldWithToggleBoldButton() {
    var rawText by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
    var count by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Column {
        BasicTextField(
            value = rawText,
            onValueChange = { value ->
                Log.d("testing", "on value change")
                if (count < 1) {
                    Log.d("testing", "here")
                    val boldedString = buildAnnotatedString {
                        withStyle(SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)) {
                            append(value.text)
                        }
                    }
                    rawText = value.copy(annotatedString = boldedString)
                    count++
                }
            },
            textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.Black),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.White)
                .padding(16.dp),
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        Button(onClick = {
            count = 0
        }) {
            Text("Toggle Bold")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why you have used count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are making changes when value it assigned that way you will not be able to solve this.

You can try my code to avoid Infinite `Recomposition`. I have already solved it.

```
@Composable
fun Ex7() {
    val testText = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
    TextField(
        value = testText.value,
        onValueChange = {
            // should only happen when you type or move cursor
            println("onValueChange called")
            testText.value = it
        },
        visualTransformation = {
            TransformedText(
                text = buildAnnotatedString {
                    withStyle(SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)) {
                        append(testText.value.text)
                    }
                },
                offsetMapping = OffsetMapping.Identity
            )
        }
    )

}
```

Comment: I just tried this solution and "onValueChange called" is printed infinetly after typing the first letter

Comment: giving you another solution

Comment: Check updated answer now you can add your logic to change text style. IT WORKS!

Comment: That's great! Can I ask you how you came up with this solution? It works for me too. I can also apply this to achieve different styles for different substrings. Thank you!

Comment: I have checked the TextField Documentation